# Webpack output is very different for ES module version and CJS modules

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a simple project setup to check how webpack bundles files.

`index.js`

```
import square from './square.js'
console.log(square(2))
```

`square.js`

```
import print from "./print.js"
print()
export default (x) => x * x;
```

`print.js`

```
export default () => {
console.log("I AM GOING TO PRINT THE SQUARE OF 2")
}
```

`webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require("path")
module.exports = {
  entry:"./index.js",
  output:{
      path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
      filename:"output.js"
  }
}
```

bundling these files using ES modules produces the following output bundle

`output.js`

```
(() => {
 "use strict";
  console.log("I AM GOING TO PRINT THE SQUARE OF 2"), console.log(2 * 2);
})();
```

**The output is very compact.**

Bundling the same using **cjs syntax** produces the following output

`index.js`

```
const square = require('./square.js')
console.log(square(2))
```

`square.js`

```
const print = require("./print.js")
print()
module.exports = (x) => x * x;
```

`print.js`

```
module.exports = () => {
console.log("I AM GOING TO PRINT THE SQUARE OF 2")
}
```

`webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require("path")
module.exports = {
  entry:"./index.js",
  output:{
  path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
  filename:"output.js"
  }
}
```

`output.js`

```
(() => {
  var o = {
      65: (o) => {
        o.exports = () => {
          console.log("I AM GOING TO PRINT THE SQUARE OF 2");
        };
      },
      698: (o, r, e) => {
        e(65)(), (o.exports = (o) => o * o);
      },
    },
    r = {};
  function e(t) {
    var s = r[t];
    if (void 0 !== s) return s.exports;
    var n = (r[t] = { exports: {} });
    return o[t](n, n.exports, e), n.exports;
  }
  (() => {
    const o = e(698);
    console.log(o(2));
  })();
})();
```

Why is the **cjs version** so much more verbose than the **esm version** even though the code is the same ?

Is it better to use es modules since the code is considerably more smaller?

Comment: Because `require` works a little differently from `exports`... scroll to the bottom of [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-node-js-require-and-es6-import-and-export/#:~:text=Require%20is%20Non%2Dlexical%2C%20it,the%20beginning%20of%20the%20file.)

Comment: I am aware of the fact that they work differently, thanks for sharing that article. My question was, assuming we can provide the same functionality using cjs/esm without the need for any special features that are unique to them like conditional imports etc. which one should we prefer given that webpack produces a more concise bundle for es modules